# laravel between two dates query error Syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-query-builder

please help me in my query . I am currently getting query error. I am new in laravel and i don't know how to make my query into laravel query. Here is my query :

```
$date1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->datepicker));
        $date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->datepicker1));

        $products =  DB::table('shipping_table')
        ->select('products.product_name', 'products.price', DB::raw('Sum(shipping_products.quantity) AS qtysold'), 'shipping_table.sold_date')
        ->join('shipping_products','shipping_table.shipping_id', '=', 'shipping_products.shipping_id')
        ->join('products','products.product_id', '=', 'shipping_products.product_id')
        ->where(['shipping_table.shipping_status', '=' ,1])
        ->whereBetween(DB::raw("date(shipping_table.sold_date"),[$date1,$date2])
        ->groupBy('products.product_name')
        ->get();
```

please take a look in `whereBetween` because i am suspecting if it's the one who has wrong syntax.

Error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Comment: I think your problem is in `date(shipping_table.sold_date` in whereBetween! The format is as same as of `$date1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->datepicker));` First check this one!

Comment: Can you please print the result of `$date1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->datepicker));` What format you get exactly?

Comment: Is it `2017-10-09` or `string(10) "2017-10-09"` ???

Comment: @HirenGohel its string(10) "2017-10-09"

Comment: What format of `date(shipping_table.sold_date)` Is it same as `$date1` format?

Comment: @HirenGohel it gives me only a date sir. with a format of Y-m-d from mysql database

Comment: Just do like: `whereBetween('DB::raw("date(shipping_table.sold_date")', [$date1." 00:00:00", $date2." 23:59:59"])`

Comment: @HirenGohel Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'whereBetween' (T_STRING)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! You are missing an ) on your between clause:

```
$date1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->datepicker));
    $date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->datepicker1));

    $products =  DB::table('shipping_table')
    ->select('products.product_name', 'products.price', DB::raw('Sum(shipping_products.quantity) AS qtysold'), 'shipping_table.sold_date')
    ->join('shipping_products','shipping_table.shipping_id', '=', 'shipping_products.shipping_id')
    ->join('products','products.product_id', '=', 'shipping_products.product_id')
    ->where('shipping_table.shipping_status',1)
    ->whereBetween(DB::raw("date(shipping_table.sold_date)"),[$date1,$date2])
    ->groupBy('products.product_name')
    ->get();
```

Try now

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: its already in good format sir here is var_dump($date1); 
string(10) "2017-10-09"

Comment: are you using strict mode? you can check it at your database connection config array (`database.php` config file)

Comment: hello sir thnks for fast reply. i already made the strict mode false

Comment: still 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: You are missing an ) , check now but maybe this 500 is another error now. I tested with my own tables and it is working